# How is jQuery UI adding elements to my DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I have a login.php file

```
  <div class="content tabs">
  </div>
```

then flush that login.php to the output html file

```
        switch ($temp) {
            case 'php':
                ob_start();
                include_once($file);
                $content = @ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                break;
```

However, when I check that login.html page which come from the login.php
there's

```
   <div class="content tabs ui-tabs ui-widget-control ui-corner-all">
  </div>
```

as you can see the div of login.php got inserted the ui-tabs ui-widget....etc from jquery ui elements..  who did that? which file insert those into the div?  It's not in any javascript files, css style sheet. but who?

Comment: it probably tries to convert `div class="tabs"` to a tab navigation widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes are added by the Jquery UI CSS framework. These the default classes added to the top container of each widget.

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0-rc.1/jquery-ui.js

Hope this helps.

Thanks
aks

Comment: OK, I check, certain divs got added by jquery ui, but other divs got ignored.  I guess my question is what's criteria in order to be added by jquery ui?

Comment: As Alex Pointed above it tries to convert the container to tab navigation widget. We have different types of widgets defined in Jquery UI like auto complete, button,dialog tabs etc and Jquery UI adds different DOM elements and css based on the type of widget defined. Usually we define such widget types with js ; something like $('.tabs').tabs(); for tab widget. Per my knowledge , jQ UI does not add any classes of its own unless specified in one way or other.

Answer (score 0):

well this are the classes which is dynamically added by jquery UI related to functionality you have used.